# Separate Android SDK for Unity project?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-2.3

I have a Unity project that uses google vr. Unfortunately, there are some incompatibilities with the newer versions of tools and platform tools in the android sdk.

I think I can just have a separate android sdk that has the older, compatible versions of these folders and put it in my Unity project. This would allow me to keep the android sdk associated with my Android Studio projects up-to-date and keep my Unity project working. BUT, it means having two copies of the android sdk... which are big (It said ~30G when I started copying my android sdk).

Is there a more elegant solution that would not take up so much space?

Comment: 30 GB means you have almost all the sdk versions downloaded and you don't need to do that usually. Just remove all other sdks, keeping the minimum version, compile version and target version only

Comment: Android API offers forward compatibility out of the box. This means that when you upgrade your API to a new level, your old applications will still work. Given that, there is no need to keep multiple versions of Android API. Just target the API level that would fit your particular app.

Comment: @Farhan I think you're right. Will take a look later. If so, I'll delete the sdk versions I don't need and copy it. Probably will be much smaller. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK is not particularly large: you can choose which parts of it you need, and install only those.

One of the things that make it so large is Android device images (emulators). If you don't need those, don't install them and it should take less space on your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

what u need to do is to specify android sdk in `Edit-Preferences-External Tools`